# For loop with grep and spaces

Tags: grep, for, whitespace

I seem to have a little bit of an issue with spaces when trying to use for loops and grep together. The whitespace is important because, for example, I'd like to match 'k117_19650 ', but not 'k117_196509 '. Help would be appreciated!

```
for i in 'k117_19650 ' 'k117_460555 ';do
    grep -A1 $i final.contigs.fa >> gene.fa
done
```

Comment: use `-w` and you will be safe when match 'k117_19650 ', but not 'k117_196509 ' for example

Comment: @RomeoNinov Worked like a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are facing is related to your use of shell variables. In particular when using variables which contain "non-standard" characters such as whitespace, *always quote your variables* when using them, see e.g. discussions here:

- [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)
- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/377345)  (these two as per Stéphane Chazelas' suggestion)
- [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) or [here](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/here-is-why-you-should-quote-your-variables-in-bash).

In your case:

```
grep -A1 -- "$i" final.contigs.fa >> gene.fa
```

should do the trick (here also adding a `--` to guard against values of `$i` that would start with `-`).

Answer (score 2):

For the purpose of such separation (match 'k117_19650 ', but not 'k117_196509 ' ) you can use `-w` in `grep` which will make it search for entire word instead of substring.

```
for i in k117_19650 k117_460555 ;do
    grep -w -A1 "$i" final.contigs.fa >> gene.fa
done
```